# Putting a line on the right of a text and then another text , so that the lines that come below have the same horizontal size. CSS

Tags: html, css

I got a problem for do some style with CSS.
I need to make a page like this:

Text-------------------------------------- $ 10

BiggerText------------------------------$ 20

BiiiiigeeerText--------------------------$ 20

A------------------------------------------ $ 10

OtherText------------------------------ $ 200

Of course, the line isn't like the example, but like HR tag line on HTML.
I have tried many styles, but i didn't found one that really works as i need.

Someone know how i can make some CSS style that allow me to put a Left text, line, then other text in same line?

Image Example:[lines-example](http://speedy.sh/fT5fN/lines.jpg)

Thanks, and Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pseudo element is ideal for this.

```css
.pricelist {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
}
.list {
  min-width: 15em;
}
.first {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #2B91AF
}
.price {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  text-align: right;
  min-width:3em;
}
.list:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 1px tomato;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricelist">
  <p class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay:</i>
    <i class="price">$150.00</i> 
  </p>
  <p class="list">
    <i class='first'>Pay:</i>
    <i class="price"> $5.00</i> 
  </p>
  <p class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay: item</i>
    <i class="price"> $15.00</i> 
  </p>
  <p class="list">
    <i class='first'>Co-Pay: great deal</i>
    <i class="price"> $1.00</i> 
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey, i found a problem! When i put prices with many numbers. like $ 100000, the configuration of line crash. The price goes below down line, and others problems. Could u help me?

Comment: Yeeah...just remove or change width on `price` - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/xdsff0b9/1/ I changed this to a min-width.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D, you help me so much! Now its really working perfectly! Great Day for you!